# calculating with the values of links

Tags: performance

I need to calculate a connection value between myself and all of my nearPersons which uses among others the trust value of the link. However, getting the trust values of all links and using these in the computation slows down the running time. I did not succeed to find another way to do it more efficiently. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

```
breed [persons person]
undirected-link-breed [connections connection]
connections-own [trust]

persons-own 
[
  nearPersons
  familiarity
]
 
to setup
  clear-all
  setupPersons
  setupConnections
  updateConnections
  reset-ticks
end

setupPersons
  create-persons 1000
  [
    set color black
    set grouped false 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end

to setupConnections
  ask persons [create-connections-with other persons]
  ask connections [ set trust 0.4]
end

to updateConnections
  while [(count persons with [grouped = false] / 1000) > 5]
  [
    let highlyTrusted n-of (2 + random 9) (persons with [grouped = false])
    ask highlyTrusted
    [
      ask my-out-connections with [member? other-end highlyTrusted] [set trust 0.6]
      set grouped true
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  getNearPersons
  calculateConnection
  forward 1
end

to getNearPersons
  ask persons [ set nearPersons other persons in-cone 3 360 ]
end

to calculateConnection
  ask persons with [nearPersons != nobody]
  [
    ask nearPersons
    [
      let degreeOfTrust [trust] of in-connection-from myself
     ]
   ]
end
```

Comment: What is the code for in-relationship-from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the model using agentsets of trust rather than links. I think that it will give you identical results, as long as there are only those two trust levels.  I made a few other changes in the code - in particular your original `while` statement would never run as it was written (the quotient was always 1).  Most are simply matters of style.  Let me know if this is not what you need.  Still not a speed demon, about 5 seconds per tick with 1000 persons, but a lot faster than the link version.  Note that nPersons is a global so that I could play around with it.

Charles

```
globals [nPersons]

breed [persons person]

persons-own
[
  nearPersons
  Trusted
  unTrusted
  familiarity
  grouped
]

to setup
  clear-all
  set nPersons 1000
  ask patches [ set pcolor gray ]
  setupPersons
  updateConnections
  reset-ticks
end

to setupPersons
  create-persons nPersons
  [
    set color black
    set grouped false
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  ask persons [
    set Trusted no-turtles
    set unTrusted persons
    set familiarity 1
  ]
end

to updateConnections
  while [(count persons with [grouped = false] / nPersons) > 0.2]
  [
    let highlyTrusted n-of (2 + random 9) (persons)  
    ; so persons can be in more than one trust group and treat all trust groups equally?
    ask highlyTrusted
    [
      set Trusted other highlyTrusted
      set grouped true
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask persons [ getNearPersons ]
  calculateConnection
  ask persons [ forward 1 ]
  tick
end

to getNearPersons
  ask persons [ set nearPersons other persons in-radius 3 ]
end

to calculateConnection
  ask persons with [any? nearPersons]
  [
    let affiliation []
    ask nearPersons
    [
      let degreeOfTrust ifelse-value (member? myself Trusted) [0.6] [0.4]
;      let degreeOfTrust [trust] of in-connection-from myself ;;this line causes netlogo to run very slowly
      set affiliation lput (degreeOfTrust * familiarity) affiliation 
     ]
   ]
end
```

Comment: Yes,  to your second comment.  Since the "Trusted" group for each person contains only those other agents who are trusted, the line
let degreeOfTrust ifelse-value (member? myself Trusted) [0.6] [0.4]
gives a trust value to each nearPerson depending on whether they are in the asking person's Trusted group.  If the nearPerson is in the asking person's Trusted group, they get a degree of trust of 0.6.  If not, 0.4.  Now that I think of it, the asking person will be included in the nearPersons group, so you likely want to exclude them with "other".

Comment: There was no value or code for familiarity, so I just set it to 1.  Also, since the asking person is not in their own trusted group, the last part of my comment above is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a few modifications of your code to make it run, I've included it below.  But I believe the real problem is just the scale of what you are doing. With 1000 persons, there are approximately half a million links that you are repeatedly polling, and given the size of your world, the number of nearPersons for each person is likely quite large.  Do you really need 1000 persons in your model, and/or do you really need every person to be connected to every other person?  The number of links goes up exponentially with the number of persons.

```
breed [persons person]
undirected-link-breed [connections connection]
connections-own [trust]

persons-own
[
  nearPersons
  familiarity
  grouped
]

to setup
  clear-all
  setupPersons
  show "persons setup"
  setupConnections
  show "connections setup"
  updateConnections
  show "connections updated"
  reset-ticks
end

to setupPersons
  create-persons nPersons
  [
    set color black
    set grouped false
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end

to setupConnections
  ask persons [create-connections-with other persons]
  ask connections [ set trust 0.4]
end

to updateConnections
  while [(count persons with [grouped = false] / 1000) > 5]
  [
    let highlyTrusted n-of (2 + random 9) (persons)
    ask highlyTrusted
    [
      ask my-out-connections with [member? other-end highlyTrusted] [set trust 0.6]
      set grouped true
    ]
  ]
end

to go
  ask persons [ getNearPersons ]
  show mean [count nearPersons] of persons
  ask persons [ calculateConnection ]
  show "got Connections"
  ask persons [ forward 1 ]
  tick
end

to getNearPersons
  ask persons [ set nearPersons other persons in-cone 3 360 ]
end

to calculateConnection
  ask persons with [nearPersons != nobody]
  [
    let affiliation []
    let idx 0
    ask nearPersons
    [
      let degreeOfTrust [trust] of in-connection-from myself ;;this line causes netlogo to run very slowly
      set affiliation insert-item idx affiliation (degreeOfTrust * familiarity)
      set idx idx + 1
     ]
   ]
end
```

Comment: I suspect that there would be a more efficient way.  E.g., if trust takes only two values, then each person could simply have an agentset of nearPersons, all of whom have a trust value of 0.6, and of all other persons with a trust value of 0.4.  Indeed, if there are only these two categories, then each person only needs to record nearPersons - all others will be "farPersons".  In general, it's better to work with agentsets rather than lists.  Let me think more on it in the morning.